# Set current date in the datetime field

Tags: mysql, datetime

There is a datetime field in the MySQL table:

```
`mytime` datetime
```

It contains entries like '2012-02-10 10:15'.

How to set the **date part** to the current date?

Comment: try now() which means **current timestamp**

Comment: @HussainTamboli That would update the time part too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138928/mysql-set-current-date-in-a-datetime-field-on-insert?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use -

```
update table tblName set mytime = current_date()
```

Or

```
update table tblName set mytime =concat(current_date(),' ',TIME(mytime))
```

Comment: This statement set the time part to 00:00:00.

Comment: @YouKuper added optional query you can use it.

Comment: It says Incorrect datetime value: '2013-01-0721:15:00' for column 'mytime' at row 1

Comment: This one works update schedule set mytime =concat(current_date(), ' ', TIME(mytime))

Comment: @JohnCruz sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 6):

Use below query..

```
update Table1 set mytime=now();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET mytime = CONCAT_WS(' ',CURDATE(), TIME(myTime))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b1ae/3)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET mytime = CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ' , time(mytime)) WHERE id = row;
```

I think this will work, my syntax may be off. `time(mytime)` may give you `hour:minute:seconds` while you are only looking for `hour:minute`. I think you also need the `' '` in there so MySQL will recognize the time format.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite vague but comes up top on a Google Search.

In general just use `now()` to set a datetime column with the current date AND time. Whether an insert, update or trigger it doesn't matter.

Several answers here have updates without a where clause. Most updates would have a where clause so as not to affect the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `table66` (
    `id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `mytime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Then you can use following query to update your mytime column

```
update table66 set mytime=concat(date(now()),' ',time(mytime) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test
SET mytime = mytime + INTERVAL DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),DATE(mytime)) DAY  ;
```