# CURRENT_DATE/CURDATE() not working as default DATE value

Tags: mysql, date, default-value

Pretty straight forward question here, I think this should work but it doesn't. Why doesn't it?

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE(
   INVOICEDATE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
)
```

Comment: _This Question is being outdated.  Newer versions allow such._  See my Answer for version numbers and their release dates.  That is, Updating may be the answer for you.

Comment: the 5th Answer is the correct one as of October 2021.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**[Edit] As of MySQl 8.0.13 it is supported. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709343/14853083) below.**

It doesn't work because it's not supported

> The `DEFAULT` clause specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for a `TIMESTAMP` column

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Comment: @inControl: yep, using `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: It's 2016 and, honestly, the fact that this still holds true is ridiculous. I thought the whole reason for constant synonyms was to allow them in places non-constant expressions were forbidden.

Comment: @NorthbornDesign I solved it for myself by migrating to postgresql :-)

Comment: please note that the answer from @NorthbornDesign is the correct one :)

Comment: For a `change_date` column (update and delete): `CREATE TABLE t1 ( ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: the 5th Answer is the correct one as of October 2021. It works!

Answer (score 57):

According to this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html), starting in MySQL 8.0.13, you will be able to specify:

```sql
CREATE TABLE INVOICE(
    INVOICEDATE DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)
)
```

MySQL 8.0.13 was released to General Availability in October 2018. The release info is located [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html).

Comment: It worked that way for me, thanks. (look at the mysql version before).

Comment: The important thing to note is that an expression has to be inside parentheses. Without parentheses the default must be a literal (except for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`).

Answer (score 32):

Currently from `MySQL 8` you can set the following to a `DATE` column:

In `MySQL Workbench`, in the `Default` field next to the column, write: `(curdate())`

If you put just `curdate()` it will fail. You need the extra `(` and `)` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Correct, Important to Note is the Extra Brackets, thanks alot

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhatri Indeed. That little detail made me lose an entire day of searching and reading documentation. It's not clearly explained and takes some trial and error for a first time user. Glad it helped, cheers!

Comment: This worked in MySQL 8.0.21. Weird syntax tho. Thank you!

Comment: @NinoŠkopac Indeed. Those weird extra brackets cost me a full day of searching. Their official documentation isn't at all clear on this aspect. Guess it's the little things ^_^. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: This should now be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu solución!!

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: I was wrong! I apologise

Comment: What signifies the extra brackets? I mean, what's the difference with or without them syntax wise? Can now the brackets work with other functions like (now()) ?

Comment: @NertanLucian Can't remember offhand but it's somewhere in the documentation if you give it a read.

Answer (score 27):

declare your date column as NOT NULL, but without a default.  Then add this trigger:

```
USE `ddb`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `default_date` BEFORE INSERT ON `dtable` FOR EACH ROW
if ( isnull(new.query_date) ) then
 set new.query_date=curdate();
end if;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I had to set field to `NULL` to make this work, otherwise it was inserting `0000-00-00` instead. MySQL v5.6.12.

Answer (score 16):

```
create table the_easy_way(
  capture_ts DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  capture_dt DATE AS (DATE(capture_ts))
)
```

(MySQL 5.7)

Comment: seems extra brackets around `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` required in recent version of mysql.

Answer (score 10):

I have the current latest version of MySQL: 8.0.20

So my table name is visit, my column name is curdate.

```
alter table visit modify curdate date not null default (current_date);
```

This writes the default date value with no timestamp.

Comment: I've tried this and successful. I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Agreed. Best answer here.

Answer (score 4):

----- 2016-07-04 MariaDB 10.2.1 -- Release Note -- -----

Support for [DEFAULT with expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default) ([MDEV-10134](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10134)).

----- 2018-10-22 8.0.13 General Availability -- -- -----

MySQL now supports use of expressions as default values in data type specifications. This includes the use of expressions as default values for the [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html), [TEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html), GEOMETRY, and [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) data types, which previously could not be assigned default values at all. For details, see [Data Type Default Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html).

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer correctly notes, you cannot use dynamic functions as a default value. You could use `TIMESTAMP` with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute, but this is not always possible, for example if you want to keep both a *creation* and *updated* timestamp, and you'd need the only allowed `TIMESTAMP` column for the second.

In this case, [use a trigger instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12936091/1729885).

Comment: The restriction on the number of automatic timestamps was lifted [in MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html).

Comment: Thanks for the addition, wasn't aware of that - still good to keep in mind since most webhosting is still at 5.1 or 5.5.

Comment: MariaDB 10.2.1 allows `DEFAULT(expression)`. See [Create table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/) .

Comment: You should add an answer @RickJames

Answer (score 3):

I came to this page with the same question in mind, but it worked for me!, Just thought to update here , may be helpful for someone later!!

```
MariaDB [niffdb]> desc invoice;
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| inv_id  | int(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cust_id | int(4) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| inv_dt  | date   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| smen_id | int(4) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [niffdb]> ALTER TABLE invoice MODIFY inv_dt DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.003 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [niffdb]> desc invoice;
+---------+--------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| Field   | Type   | Null | Key | Default   | Extra          |
+---------+--------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| inv_id  | int(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment |
| cust_id | int(4) | NO   | MUL | NULL      |                |
| inv_dt  | date   | NO   |     | curdate() |                |
| smen_id | int(4) | NO   | MUL | NULL      |                |
+---------+--------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [niffdb]> SELECT VERSION();
+---------------------------+
| VERSION()                 |
+---------------------------+
| 10.3.18-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.010 sec)

MariaDB [niffdb]>
```

Comment: worked for me `DEFAULT LAST_DAY(CURDATE())` even without parentheses. some phpmyadmin functions might trigger error though

Answer (score 1):

While creating a table, you have to use `CURRENT_DATE()` function as default value. Please see below example I just tested.

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_DATA (
    SALES_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SALES_GIRL_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    SALES_DATE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE()),
    TOTAL_SALES FLOAT(6, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (SALES_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SALES_GIRL_ID) REFERENCES SALES_GIRLS(ID)
);
```