# How to give current date as default in MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20),
    species VARCHAR(20), sex CHAR(1), joindate DATE default now(), death DATE)
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'joindate'    0.000 sec

Comment: use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default after changing the data type to `timestamp`

Comment: Check this answer on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461030/current-date-curdate-not-working-as-default-date-value), like @hnn said....

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate.  However, it is important to understand that `date` and `datetime` can have such defaults in MySQL 5.6+.

Comment: So, Could you please provide alternative ways to achieve. ie. I have to have join_data with default value is current date in mysql5.5. I am not perticular to Date data type. even date and time combination also no issue.