# MySQL DATE field with default CURDATE(). NOT DATETIME

Tags: mysql, date, default

It is possible to set default value on DATE (**NOT DATETIME**) column in MySQL 5.7 to current date?
I try this (generated by Workbench):

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`table` CHANGE COLUMN `column` `column` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE() ;
```

but not works for me.
(no data in table)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot.  The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) is pretty clear on this:

> This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date
>   column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.
>   The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default
>   for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns. See Section 12.3.5, “Automatic
>   Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME”.

You can do one of the following:

- Set up a column with a default value for the `DATETIME`.  Create view that extracts the date as a separate column.
- Create an `insert` trigger to set the `date` column.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can do this if you have another column that has a for example a datetime field with a default of NOW().  [See this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461030/current-date-curdate-not-working-as-default-date-value/54119983#54119983)