# Date column with DEFAULT CURDATE() throw error

Tags: mysql, date

```
CREATE TABLE tests(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
day DATE DEFAULT CURDATE());
```

This code gives me error message: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURDATE()

I do not understand why. It works without DEFAULT CURDATE()

Can someone explains me why?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808684/mysql-date-field-with-default-curdate-not-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL DATE field with default CURDATE(). NOT DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808684/mysql-date-field-with-default-curdate-not-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

curdate() is date time function your assigning current date to a date variable

```
CREATE TABLE tests( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `day` datetime DEFAULT now())
```

run this query

Comment: But what if I just want the DATE type? I do not want the HH:MM:SS part at all.