# Mysql. ERROR 1064(42000) in syntax

Tags: mysql

**Hello! I can't understand what's a problem?**

```
CREATE TABLE expenses(
  num INT,
  paydate DATE DEFAULT DATE(),
  receiver INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  value DEC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(num)
);
```

**And I have a problem:**

> ERROR 1064(42000):You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(), receiver INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, value
>   DEC(10,2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(num))' at line 4

Comment: See [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461030/current-date-curdate-not-working-as-default-date-value) for using a trigger

Comment: If you use MariaDB: "From MariaDB 10.2.1 you can use most functions in DEFAULT" (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/). So the following would work: `paydate DATE DEFAULT CURDATE()`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not let you default only the date.  You need to default a `datetime`:

```
CREATE TABLE expenses (
  num INT,
  paydate datetime DEFAULT now(),
  receiver INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  value DEC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (num)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d04e) is a SQL Fiddle.