# How to alter column to set default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a table later I want to add a default value for the column as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_date` date DEFAULT NULL,  -- this column...
  `order_status` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

my alter query is like

```
ALTER TABLE `orders` CHANGE `order_date` `order_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and I got error like

```
 Query error:
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'order_date'
```

Comment: You can also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461030/current-date-curdate-not-working-as-default-date-value

Comment: You can't assign a `DATE` datatype column with a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default value. Just go with Jim's solution and do your query to something like this `WHERE order_date LIKE  '2020-06-27%'` or `WHERE DATE(order_date)='2020-06-27'`.

Answer (score 3):

Please use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
    MODIFY column_1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

In your case the statement would be as below,

```
ALTER TABLE `orders` 
    MODIFY `order_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: The first line changes the type, which may or may not be acceptable, and the second line won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your column needs to be of type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.  [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).  Aside from changing the column type, which you may not want to do, you could write an INSERT/UPDATE trigger.