# date(now()) giving "'(' is not valid at this position, expecting 'text'" in MySQL 8.0.22

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to learning SQL and database creation/management and I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to find an existing answer for.  I'm using MySQL to learn right now and I'm running version 8.0.22.  I'm trying to use the date function to extract the date portion of the result from now() to use as a default value, but it's giving me the error specified in the title.

I have tried a couple things and they haven't seemed to change anything.

This is what I tried first.

```
INV_DATE DATE DEFAULT date(now()) NOT NULL,
```

I then tried it like:

```
INV_DATE DATE DEFAULT date'2016-01-01' NOT NULL,
```

Just to see if that worked syntactically and it did.
NOW() on its own works when I change the DATE datatype to DATETIME.

I'm just not really sure what's going on here with this function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: This is the context in which this is being run.

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
INV_NUMBER INTEGER,
INV_DATE DATE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(INV_NUMBER),
FOREIGN KEY (CUS_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUS_CODE) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

The reason I'm trying to use now() as a default value is because the learning material I'm using jumps between dialects to demonstrate things and is using Oracle SQL for this part. It shows:

```
INV_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
```

And I was trying to convert it into the MySQL equivalent.

Comment: This is a `CREATE TABLE ..` syntax isn't it?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes, this is one of the attributes being defined in a table.

Comment: I am familiar with `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` datatype having `DEFAULT` value of `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` in MySQL but I don't think there's one for `DATE` value. [Fiddle for further tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4cf746abde01f8a6afb900860482b6de).

Comment: @tcadidot0 Gotcha.  With that being the case, the date function that I was trying to use originally should be used with timestamp literals?  Like date('2016-01-01 23:50:26') and not with a function as the expression being passed in?  Such as date(now()).  I only ask because I have seen date(now()) in a ton of examples online.

Comment: If you need a column of DATE datatype which' default value is current date you may use either generated column or trigger.

Comment: Please share the full query you are using, not just some parts

Comment: For queries, there's no problem using `DATE(NOW())`. I think that was the one you see being used in examples. See this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e8da7c5fabe82bdb0ca9a7d29dea80f

Comment: @NicoHaase I just included it.  I had accidentally formatted it wrong in my original edit, so it didn't show fully.

Comment: @tcadidot0 *For queries, there's no problem using DATE(NOW())* Using DATETIME column instead of DATE may result in increased query complexity when this column must be used in some complex condition. As a final result this may decrease performance.

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes, I understand now.  It was specifically in the way I was using it that was causing the issue.

Comment: Ah yes @Akina , thanks for clarifying that. Probably what I meant was using `DATE(NOW())` in between creating table and using it as a query. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rule** - `now()` is not allowed as a default value for the `date` data type column.

Also, If you want to use `now()` in your query then you don't need `date(now())` only `now()` is enough.

Check the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8132600e3cc78fc84a2204517e7bc6e) to see the error with `now()` as default value and without it.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  The learning material I'm using switches between different sql dialects to teach its concepts and this particular example was using Oracle sql.  It was:INV_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL
Does that not convert over to MySQL in this case since now() can't be used?

Comment: *Rule - now() is not allowed as a default value for the column.* - this is true for DATE datatype column only. But it is valid for DATETIME/TIMESTAMP column and even for numeric/string datatypes (in a form `DEFAULT (now())`). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=988abb8a5d857dd82cfb7e6e0e620d1d

Comment: @Akina Thanks!  That makes sense.  I think I'm understanding what the problem was now.

Comment: Yes @Akina, Sample code is based on the DATE data type. so mentioned it. but let me mention it here.

Comment: @Akina I haven't gotten to triggers yet, so I have some more learning to do.  My original question has been answered so I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461030/current-date-curdate-not-working-as-default-date-value/62148285#62148285

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow default values for `date` columns.  You have two reasonable alternatives.

The first is to use a trigger to assign the date value when you `insert` new rows.

The second is to use a `datetime` column along with a generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICES (
    INV_NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    INV_DATETIME DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
    INV_DATE DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(INV_DATETIME))
);
```

You can use a view (or other mechanisms) to hide the `INV_DATETIME` column.  However, you need to update `INV_DATETIME` because `INV_DATE` is generated based on that column.