# SQL DEFAULT AND TIME

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    OrderDate date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE()
);
```

It is not working in MySQL Workbench, here is the given error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
> Executing:
> CREATE TABLE `xyz`.`order` (
> `id` INT NOT NULL,
> `o_no` INT NULL,
> `o_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(),
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
>
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE(),
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`))' at line 4
> SQL Statement:
> CREATE TABLE `xyz`.`order` (
> `id` INT NOT NULL,
> `o_no` INT NULL,
> `o_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(),
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

I want a column with default date

Comment: Not only in MySQL Workbench, but simply always in MySQL this throws an error:  see: https://dbfiddle.uk/QkmHHOpy with the same error.

Comment: the error says : "near 'CURRENT_DATE()" more info here: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score -1):

For versions of MySQL prior to version 8, you need to set the field's data type to either timestamp or datetime and use "current_timestamp" as the default, so this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders ( OrderNumber int NOT NULL, OrderDate datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

There are other aliases you can use instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, for example now() - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html for the full details.

When you need to get the order's date, just use the DATE() function to chop off the time part, so you could use this in a view or select query:

```
SELECT ....., DATE(`OrderDate`) FROM `Orders`
```

**EDIT**: As Shadow has pointed out, as from MySQL version 8 you can do this, allowing you to have a DATE data type for the field:

```
 CREATE TABLE Orders ( OrderNumber int NOT NULL, OrderDate DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)
```

I will leave the original answer in place for people who are using an older version of MySQL.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: @shadow please can you explain why you think it is outdated, or can you provide an answer that you think isn't outdated? I'm looking at the MySQL 8 reference.

Comment: Check out this answer provided to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709343/5389997